# Want to execute a local sql file (using \i to execute multiple sql files) using psql command on ssh server

Tags: postgresql, ssh, psql

I have multiple `.sql` files on my local machine, which I was executing rapidly with one command 
`psql .....-f abc.sql` (containing \i def.sql; \i ghi.sql) on db server hosted on aws.

Now, I have established SSH tunneling with this db server and want to execute my local sql files on this server to rapidly create, drop, update objects on db hosted on aws.

I have tried 
1. `cat abc.sql | ssh -i abc.pem user@server.com psql -c`

simple : How to execute my local files on SSH server using psql command?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the -c at the end of the command.   However, when the script encounters the \i command, it will try to load the files locally from the server.  You will either have to send them there via scp, or include them completely inline to the master script.